# Use Javascript/Jquery to add a SPAN inside P tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a paragraph tag with a class of "price" which I want to add a span tag inside using either Javascript, Jquery or both.

E.g

BEFORE: `<p class="price"></p>`

AFTER: `<p class="price"><span class="whatever">Sale</span></p>`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
$("p.price").append($(`<span class="whatever">Sale</span>`));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is plain JavaScript code

```js
function addSpan() {
  var price = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0];
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.classList.add('whatever');
  span.innerText = 'Sale';
  price.appendChild(span);
}

addSpan();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p class="price"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

You can make the method more generic by passing parameters as well.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! This only works when I paste it into the console via the inspector of Chrome. When I try and embed it in <script></script> tags on the header of my site it doesn't do anything and throws an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined at addSpan"

Comment: Can you try putting this code after your dom has rendered? I guess, when you are running the code, the DOM is not even rendered. So that's why you are getting `price` as `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

To add it within the **first** `.price` element, without jQuery:

```
document.querySelector(".price").insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<span class='whatever'></span>"
);
```

With jQuery:

```
$(".price").first().append("<span class='whatever'></span>");
```

If you know there's only one, you can leave out `.first()`.

Answer (score 0):

if need vanilla javascript:

```js
   var lcs_els = document.getElementsByClassName('price');

   for(var key in lcs_els){
      lcs_els[key].innerHTML = '<span class="whatever">Sale</span>';
   }
```

```html
<p class="price"></p>
```

if need jquery:

```js
$('.price').html('<span class="whatever">Sale</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="price"></p>
```

Jquery variant 2  if need manipulate of span:

```js
   var span = $('<span/>').attr('class', 'whatever').html('Sale');
   $('.price').append(span);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <p class="price"></p>
```